# Is there a simple way to make scaffolding pluralization "less clever"?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an existing database that I'm using for scaffolding. Like:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Trust Server Certificate=True" 
       Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
       --use-database-names --context DatabaseContext   
       --context-dir DataGenerated --output-dir ModelsGenerated 
       --no-onconfiguring --force
```

Let's say it contains the tables:

- Car
- Dog
- Person

Then I will get:

- `public virtual DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }` - fine
- `public virtual DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }` - fine
- `public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }` - NO. This disturbs me. Please give me "Persons", not "People"

Is there a switch or something that can fix this without diving deep into the templates or changing it manually after scaffolding?

Comment: Disable pluralization. Or try EF Core Power Tools

Comment: Or just change the class name after scaffolding.